# Best Practice in converting Input element from hidden to visible

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

What is the best practice (and modern) to implement a script that can take input hidden-typed textbox and make it visible (following some user button press or so).

```
<input name="someName" class="field" id="ID1" type="hidden" value=""></input>

<a id="ID2" href="#">Do It</a>

<script>    
    $('a').click(function () {
        // What to implement here?? how to make the input element to be visible?
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cannot change the type directly of an input element you will need to clone the element and then change the elements `type` attribute to the one the input should be, text,password,number,date etc, then replace the original with the new.

```
$('a').click(function () {
    $("#ID1").replaceWith( $("#ID1").clone().attr("type","text") );
});
```

[jQuery's clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone)

[jQuery's replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)